# deadlock at beginner level code

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock

here is my main function's body;

```
c := make(chan int)

go func() {

    i := <-c
    i++
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

    c <-i


}()

time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
go func() {
    i := <-c
    i++
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    c <-i

}()

time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
fmt.Println(<-c)
```

i am getting deadlock error.even i've tried with waitgroups.hella ripped my hair.

explaining answer would be great for me.

Comment: Nothing writes to `c`, so all 3 threads are locked reading from it.

Comment: i've just added "c <- 0" before println,it works but when i add that before first go func i got same deadlock error.wth happenings?

Comment: @KadirSusuz When you add the write operation before spawning the first goroutine, you are trying to write to an unbuffered channel. This operation blocks until the value is read from the channel, but you haven't started the goroutines to read from it. The solution would be to start the goroutines first or create a buffered channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add before the last line:

```
c <- 0
```

This way you give start value which could be read by goroutines to start working. Also you can add to both goroutines before the last line (sending to channel) add printing goroutine number and value:

```
fmt.Println("goroutine 1 value", i)
```

This you can see how values are passed in situation of 3 possible consumers of the same item in channel. Most likely the main goroutine will read the channel and you get `0`. Add `Sleep` to give others a chance. Play with sleep time toget different results.

Comment: i've just added "c <- 0" before println,it works but when i add that before first go func i got same deadlock error.wth happenings?

Comment: Quite right - because at that moment there's no goroutine which can read from the channel. So writing to channel is blocked until someone starts to read from the channel. Try to place writing between starting readers. Another way: you may make you channel buffered - that means it can store several elements inside. The rule is the same: you can write to channel if there's a room for new elements, if there's no room writer gets blocked. If there's a reader, it will read elements and thus free space for new ones. How to create a buffered channel? `make(chan int, 10)` - here 10 buf len

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from the channel before writing to it, so everything deadlocks waiting for a read that can never happen.

You could break the deadlock by putting `c <- 0` before your call to `Printf`, but the program could then print 0, 1, or 2. Note that if you put the initial send before you start the first goroutine  you get the same problem from the other direcion, a send with no possible reads.

If you said what you were trying to do it would be far easier to help, as it is I can't really provide any specific pointers.

Comment: "with 0 being by far the most likely result." --- that's what I thought as well, but it's 2 on play.golang. On a single cpu machine 2 is more likely.

Comment: Where exactly you put the first send, and where you sleep would be the main influences on a single core machine, but who runs single core machines nowadays? :P If you sleep right after the first send things become pretty unpredictable on multiple cores.

Comment: i've just added "c <- 0" before println,it works but when i add that before first go func i got same deadlock error.wth happenings?

Comment: Oh, yeah... That is obvious once I think about it, and I should have thought to mention it in the answer. In that case you have a (blocking) send with no possible reads. You can either make the channel buffered, or make sure at least one of the goroutines has started before the first send.

Answer (score 0):

You Got an Unbuffered channels which means your working "synch" i mean when using an unbuffered channel you need a writer and a reader to achieve something try buffered channels as you can try a select to wait for messages.
2 - you are reading before writing from an unbuffered channel which will block till a write operation happens. so you got 2 readers from a blocked channel ( because there's no writer).